# Select top 10 rows from database and display result randomly

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to display trending Ads on my site on the basis of number of clicks.

My SQL Query looks like this:

```
  SELECT  ad_id, clicks from ads ORDER BY  clicks DESC LIMIT 5

Result:
ad_id   clicks
3393    2204
4495    1208
2399    932
2780    777
3316    679
```

I want to display this result randomly every time page refresh.

I tried using

```
SELECT  * from ads ORDER BY  clicks DESC, RAND() LIMIT 10
```

But this is not working giving the same result every time on page refresh.

If I use like:

```
SELECT  ad_id, clicks from ads ORDER BY RAND(), clicks DESC LIMIT 10
ad_id   clicks
9762    0
6305    1
4040    17
11598   0
11347   0
```

It is showing data randomly but now the highest number of clicks is zero.

Can you suggest me how to display top clicks result randomly on every page refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get top 10 rows and then display them in random order, use this:

```
select *
from (
    select *
    from ads
    order by clicks desc LIMIT 10
    ) t
order by rand() desc
```

If you want to get 10 randomly chosen records sorted in descending order of clicks, try this:

```
select *
from (
    select *
    from ads
    order by RAND() LIMIT 10
    ) t
order by clicks desc
```

It finds 10 random records in subquery and then sorts it afterwards.

Or perhaps you want to get 10 random records out of some top , say 100, rows sorted in descending order of clicks:

```
select *
from (
    select *
    from (
        select *
        from ads
        order by click desc LIMIT 100  -- change this as per your needs
        ) t
    order by rand() limit 10
    ) t
order by clicks desc
```

Comment: Thanks for response but it is not working. It is selecting random rows and out of that random rows giving top click on top. Not selecting top 10 clicks

Comment: Perfect working fine if I select out of 100 clicks it is giving me top 10 results randomly. But if I want to select only top 10 clicks and display it randomly it is showing same result every time.

Comment: @Kritika - Added that too. See the first query.